# How to get BottomSheetScaffold to stick the TopAppBar

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet, jetpack

I've looked at the Material Design 3 behavior of the bottomsheet, and I saw this https://m3.material.io/components/bottom-sheets/guidelines#36f26e35-0765-45a7-a0b8-f0c7c68a380c where the BottomSheet kind of sticks/clamps to the bottom of the `TopAppBar` or other widget, whereafter the whole sheet "integrates" into the screen.
I was hoping this was available in the `StandardBottomSheetState`, or, anywhere - but I cannot find it.
Essentially this is implemented in the google maps app, so I assumed this would be an available animation/feature.
Can anyone help me with this?
Or do I have to figure out some animations on my own?

Comment: I've now seen that when I add a `Surface with` a `shadowElevation` to the `DragHandle` in the `BottomSheet`, that shadow is progressively removed the further up the `BottomSheet` is, so at fully expanded I cannot see any `shadow` on my `Surface`, and at `PartiallyExpanded` or `sheetPeekHeight` I can see the shadow fine - I think this may be the way Google did it on the their Maps application.